# Right-aligning an image to the page border in a r-markdown PDF document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm looking to create a cover page for a PDF document rendered via rmarkdown, with an image `cover.png` that I'd have right-aligned right up against the page border. In my YAML below, I currently have it centered on the page. How do I move it to the right?

```
---
title: \vspace{3cm} \fontsize{1.5cm}{2cm}\selectfont Report Title
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=20cm]{cover.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `\hspace*{2cm}` before `\includegraphics` to move it to as far right as I want. I used trial and error to move it to the edge of the page. I got the answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107346).

```
---
title: \vspace{3cm} \fontsize{1.5cm}{2cm}\selectfont Report Title
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}\hspace*{2cm}\includegraphics[width=20cm]{cover.png}\\[\bigskipamount]}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include raw latex in your Rmd doc that will situate the picture where you want it. For example:

````
---
title: Dogs are the best
output:
  pdf_document:
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r include = FALSE}
library(httr)
dog <- "https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg"
GET(dog, write_disk("dog.jpg", overwrite = TRUE))
```

\begin{figure}
  \raggedleft
  \begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width = 5cm]{dog.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

## Introduction

Dogs dogs dogs
````

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. I did want the picture above the title, however. I found that adding `\hspace*{2cm}` before `\includegraphics` got it done.

Comment: The answer was a minimal example of the functionality that you could use to right align an image on a title page